# Google Apps Script - why .getNextDataCell() skips data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to start at the top of a column and perform <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to arrive at a non-empty cell on row 15.

There is data in that column on rows 1, 15, and 16 *only*. When I use the following script to start on row 1 and try to go down to 15, my script skips rows 15 & 16 and goes to the bottom of the sheet, row 2000.

When I try to Record Macro and perform this function, it works fine while I'm recording, but skips the non-empty cells when I try to call the macro.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function DOWN() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('Q1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
}
```

Comment: Where is `column` of `There is data in that column on rows 1, 15, and 16 ONLY.`? In your script, the column "Q" is used. So when `column` is not the column "Q", `getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)` doesn't return "Q15". How about this?

Comment: getNextDataCell can't to be used for consecutive next, it will go to first and last for some consecutive not blank cell, for example if c4, c5 and c6 are not blank cells, so if you first are in c1, getnextdatacell give you c4, and from c4 getnextdatacell give c6.

Comment: Welcome, Matt L. I may have misunderstood you, but with data in only cells Q1, Q15 and Q16, I then ran script `DOWN`, and it is fine. Moved the cursor to Q15 as expected

Comment: Based on the behaviour you describe, I would say column Q is empty, and it is another column the one that has data in rows 1, 15 and 16. Please check that, or share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on so that we can be sure that's the case.

Comment: @Tanaike the data is in column Q.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you!  Yeah, it's continuing past those cells on mine.  There is text in cells Q15 and Q16.  I don't know if formatting matters?  Seems like it shouldn't.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If there is text, it should not skip it. Can you share your spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that the discussions have been advanced. I think that your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function TestNextNonBlank() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mysheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MainSheet');
  var myrange=mysheet.getRange('Q1'); 

  myrange=nextNonBlank(myrange); //First Non Blank
  Logger.log(myrange.getA1Notation()); //Give Q15

  myrange=nextNonBlank(myrange); //Second Non Blank
  Logger.log(myrange.getA1Notation()); //Give Q16

  myrange=nextNonBlank(myrange); //Third Non Blank
  Logger.log(myrange.getA1Notation()); //Give Q994

};


function nextNonBlank(theRange)
{
  if (theRange.offset(1, 0).isBlank()==false) return theRange.offset(1, 0);
  theRange=theRange.offset(1, 0);
  if (theRange.offset(1, 0).isBlank()==false) return theRange.offset(1, 0);
  theRange=theRange.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
  return theRange;
}
```

To Avoid the invalid argument error, below I have modified the script of function, after this function reach the max row, it return the range in the max row position. To have the script run well, we must ensure the valid sheet and the valid position of non blank cell:

```
function nextNonBlank(theRange)
{
  if (theRange.getSheet().getMaxRows()==theRange.getRowIndex()){
     return theRange; 
  }
  //save the range as last range
  var storedRange=theRange;
  if (theRange.offset(1, 0).isBlank()==false) return theRange.offset(1, 0);
  theRange=theRange.offset(1, 0);
  if (theRange.offset(1, 0).isBlank()==false) return theRange.offset(1, 0);
  theRange=theRange.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
  //if the reach range is blank, back to use the stored range
  if (theRange.isBlank()) theRange=storedRange;
  return theRange;
}
```

Comment: So I tried this, when I try it attempting to log all 3 ranges, it gives me an error "Invalid Argument".  When I comment out the second and third "myrange" and "Logger" lines for Q16 and Q994 and check the log, it logged cell Q2000.  Like I mentioned in a previous comment, I don't know if formatting matters, but I've changed it from "Date" format to "Automatic" or "Number" without success.  When I use CTRL + DOWN outside of a script, it lands on Q15, then Q16, then Q2000.

Comment: Q2000 or q994 is depended on our total rows have, in mine last row is 994, ok can you share you sample sheet? And please let me know, the log result after you run my script.

Comment: "Invalid Argument" is because you have reach last row, you can't move to the next row after that.

Comment: please try add this Logger.log(therRange.getSheet().getSheetName()); in function nextNonBlank, please look at your log, is the sheet name same as your aim

Answer (score 0):

Foiled again!  Before this step in my process, I copied and pasted the column as values.  The formula in Q2:Q had been =if(H2="","",Today()).  When I copy and paste as values, there were hidden characters that caused the apparently blank cells to "contain data".  Though I'm not sure why there would be hidden characters, this appears to be the answer to that problem. If anybody knows how to avoid the hidden characters, I'd appreciate any tips you have. I also find it strange that outside of a script, I could do CTRL + DOWN and it would skip to the only visible data.